# How to check for Delete character in keyDown function?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my custom NSView, I am looking to detect the Delete key press. Here's my code -

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
  NSString * characters = theEvent.characters;
  
  if (characters != nil && characters.length > 0) {
    NSString* firstchar = [characters substringToIndex:1];
    
    //0x007F is the unicode delete character
    if ([firstchar isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x007F]]) {
      //delete character detected, do something
      return;
    }
  }
  
  [super keyDown:theEvent];
}
```

Doesn't work!! The delete character isn't detected.

**Update:** the following code works!

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
  unichar key = [[event charactersIgnoringModifiers] characterAtIndex:0];
  if(key == NSDeleteCharacter || key == NSBackspaceCharacter || key == NSDeleteFunctionKey)
  {
    //delete character detected, do something
    return;
  }
  
  [super keyDown:event];
}
```

Comment: Use the key code?

Comment: What is the value of `firstchar` when you type a Delete?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSTableView + Delete Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668847/nstableview-delete-key)

Comment: @Willeke It doesn't work, the key == NSDeleteCharacter comparison is false!

Comment: Are you typing a Delete or a Backspace? What is the value of `key`?

Comment: @Willeke Typing a Backspace works with the second code! I mean key == NSDeleteCharacter is true when I type Backspace. How do I get Delete key to work as well?

Comment: Try `NSBackspaceCharacter`.

Comment: @Willeke NSBackspaceCharacter doesn't work.

Comment: How about `NSClearLineFunctionKey`?

Comment: NSResponder - (void)deleteBackward:(nullable id)sender;  is the correct answer. Make sure your view is in the responder chain